# ProFTPD SFTP authentication banner

Tags: sftp, proftpd

I installed and configured ProFTPD with SFTP option. But when I'm connecting to the service via WinSCP or native OpenSSH `scp` client, after I enter the user credentials, I get banner similar to SSH motd.

```
Linux debian1 4.19.0-12-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.152-1 (2020-10-18) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
You have mail.
```

How can I disable it? I've tried various "Display" options, but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSH authentication banner is configured in ProFTPD using the [`SFTPDisplayBanner` directive](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html#SFTPDisplayBanner). Though this is sent *before* authentication.

---

Another source of the banner can be server's PAM module. You can disable forwarding of the banner from PAM to the client using [`SFTPPAMOptions` directive](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp_pam.html#SFTPPAMOptions) with `NoInfoMsgs` flag.